# NPM is completely ignoring globally installed packages

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I'm having a problem with installing packages locally, where globally installed packages are available. There seems to be a problem with the include path, but I am not sure what this is causing.

System : Mac OS X
Node   : 8.3.1
NPM    : 5.0.4

Output for `npm list -g --depth=0`

```
/usr/local/lib
+-- node-gyp@3.6.2
+-- node-sass@4.5.3
+-- npm@5.0.4
`-- npm-check@5.4.4
```

When I'm trying to install it first mentions `node-gyp` which *is* installed globally, unlike the warning. And after that it fails with `node-sass` which is *also* installed globally.

```
jurriendokter$ npm install
npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.6.1 should be installed with -g

> node-sass@4.5.2 install /Users/jurriendokter/Development/holland-toolkit/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'extend'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jurriendokter/Development/holland-toolkit/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/request/index.js:17:29)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@https://registry.npmjs.org/node-sass/-/node-sass-4.5.2.tgz (node_modules/node-sass):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.5.2 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

added 291 packages in 7.829s
```

I have reinstalled node on mac osx, checked `npm doctor` and everything, but I'm at a total loss.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I found that if you previously installed packages using an older NPM version (3 or 4), and subsequently install a package using a newer version (5), the latter may get confused. This happens to me both for local and global packages. Usually fixed by force-installing the new package (`npm i --force ...`). I think the `node-gyp` warning has to do with it being declared a dependency for `node-sass`, so `npm i node-sass` would (also) install a local version of it, which may trigger the warning (because `node-gyp` has `preferGlobal` set in `package.json`).

Comment: That may very well have been the case in my situation. Removing the `package-lock.json` from the filesystem also treats every install as a new one (or forced one), so that helped as well. 

I found out that if you install a different version, but do not use `--save` and thus update `package-lock.json`, it'll install the version from `package-lock.json` instead of the version that is set in `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this using the following procedure.

- `npm cache clear --force`
- `rm -rf node_modules`
- `rm package-lock.json`
- `npm install`
- `npm update`

Mind that this does not solve the warning: `npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.6.2 should be installed with -g` but it allows me to install and run my scripts again.